# Progress Bar in Background Worker not loading

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I've run into an issue that I can't seem to figure out the solution to, I've read several answers and have gotten as far as knowing that I need a BackgroundWorker Thread to make this solution work, but I'm still running into a bit of an issue.

I have a second form that is a small size and set to center on screen with a ProgressBar Style set to Marquee, there is nothing else on this second form as it is meant to emulate a loading bar.

In my data intensive section of the code, on the main form, where it grabs and parses data from a database I have it written like this:

```
 GetData()
 {
      bwLoading.RunWorkerAsync();
      //Runs all the processing
      bwLoading.CancelAsync();
 }
```

The background worker is defined as such below, also on the main form.

```
 private void bwLoading_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        frmLoading lb = new frmLoading();
        bool running = true;
        while (running)
        {
            if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                lb.Close();
                running = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lb.Show();
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem I have run into is that with this method it shows the Loading form that contains the progress bar does show up when the data starts getting gathered and process and does disappear when the data load is complete, but the window is empty like it's trying to load, but it doesn't. I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.

Isn't the background worker creating a separate thread for the Loading form to use? Or is there something else that I'm missing from my reading?

Comment: Why the CancelAsync ? Tried removing that?

Comment: And: do not Create or Show a Form inside DoWork().

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't believe you are understanding my question properly. I am showing a "busy" box while it is processing. The cancel is so that the background worker knows when to hide the "busy" box.

Comment: THe "busy box" does not need a Thread (better not) but the 'processing' part does. So indeed, I don't get it.

Comment: And how often does that loop inside DoWork() run? Looks like it could be cooking the CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to actually report the progress of your background operation using [`ReportProgress()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx). This requires you knowing how much percent of your work you have completed.

If you do not report progress, the progress bar will always remain at 0% until your background operation is completed, and disappear afterwards - which is what you are observing.

Edit:

In light of your comment - you are using a marquee style progress bar - I think the problem is here:

```
 GetData()
 {
      bwLoading.RunWorkerAsync();
      //Runs all the processing
      bwLoading.CancelAsync();
 }
```

I suspect you execute the `GetData()` method from the UI thread - that means the UI thread is blocked and the progress bar cannot be updated. Move all your processing to the `bwLoading_DoWork` method so it is executed on a separate thread and not the UI thread - then your progress bar should get updated. Also remove the `bwLoading.CancelAsync()` call - this would be used only for cancellation.

Comment: But the form is set to a marquee style. Does that still require a progress to be reported?

Comment: Or am I misunderstanding it and that I need a Background worker on the Load of the second form?

Comment: @JKM: No you are correct, I missed the Marquee style - you should not have to report progress in that case, so the problem is someplace else. Did you set the progress bar to visible?

Comment: Yes, it is set to true. The progress bar loads just fine if I use the .ShowDialog method, but that is not what I want it to do as it never ends. That's why I was thinking I could use the .CancelAsync() option to close the popup. I've tried putting the GetData in the DoWork method, and doing that call from there, but the "loading" window simply pops up and disappears because the Get Data is run in a different thread.